# How to convert string into proper xml read in from file?

Tags: c#, xml

I read in data from a csv file(which is out of my control) to a string variable and then split it out into a string array.  One of the elements will contain an xml string.  Hovering over the string shows this:

```
 "\"<xyz test=\"\"gc\"\"></xyz>\""
```

I am trying to convert this into a proper xml string and to no avail.  I have tried to use XElement.Parse but it returns an error.

So in Linqpad:

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
var items = contents.Split(",");        
string xml = items[7].ToString();
xml.Dump();
var pxXml = XElement.Parse(xml);
```

returns:

```
"<xyz test=""gc""><dataitem/></xyz>"
XmlException
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

Is there a better way to get a proper formatted xml string from my csv file?

Contents of the csv file

```
5,e823a08a-c141-4f3c-95a3-a2b284ee90a6,TOP,XXXXX,FR,2022/04/27 08:05:39.0707470,2022/04/27 12:05:39.0707470,"<xyz test=""gc""><dataitem/></xyz>",
```

The actual code in project

```
private string ExtractXmlFromCsv(string fileName)
{
   string contents = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
   var items = contents.Split(","); 
   string xml = items[7].ToString();

   var pxXml = XElement.Parse(xml);   //<--- breaks here

   return pxXml.ToString();
}
```

Comment: "Hovering over the string" - using what tool?

Comment: start tag is <xyx and end/close tag is  different </xyz

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  using visual studio... i moved the code over to linqpad to more easily work on the problem.  The solution this is from rather huge.  I often use linqpad to debug or work on small portions of code.

Comment: @oleg this was a typo...

Comment: It'd probebly be most helpful if you posted the raw CSV sample from where you got the string in the first place (and perhaps the code with which you read/parsed the file) :)

Comment: You have two double quotes at the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  have updated post to include the csv content and the actual method.  Again the method in the code is the same I am testing in Linqpad with the exception of the line with "Dump".

Comment: @jdweng  the double quotes you are referring to are what is shown when you hover over the xml variable... .

Comment: No.  It is really two sets of double quotes.  Copy the string to notepad and check.

Comment: `items[7].Trim('"').Replace("\"\"", "\"");`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov - That worked!  if you would care to post it as a reply I will mark it as the answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to get your string in the correct format. Try this.

```
    private string ExtractXmlFromCsv(string fileName)
    {
        string contents = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
        var items = contents.Split(",");
        string xml = items[7].ToString();

        var rawXml = xml.Trim('"').Replace("\"\"", "\"");

        var pxXml = XElement.Parse(rawXml); 

        return pxXml.ToString();
    }
```